# Set retention days to a Elasticsearch indices, using kibana or Elasticsearch itself

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, retention, elasticsearch-indices

I have some indices that I have to apply retention policies to.

**Indice-a**-*date_of_creation*   **30 days**
**Indice-b**-*date_of_creation*   **180 days**

Is there a way to set retention policies to those Indices on Kibana?
If not, how can I set them on elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ELK 6.6 (XPack) there is index lifecycle management.

In the ELK 7.16 you can use Index Lifecycle Policies in kibana

> Stack Management > Index Lifecycle Policies. Click Create policy.

---

**In older versions** as your indexes contain timestamp you can write script to generate list of indexes to delete and then run loop over such list and call
curl -XDELETE